# I want to remove ubuntu 11.10 and try kubuntu 11.04 but I can't get my Kubuntu live disc to work

Tags: 11.10, uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “malformed line” errors in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152184/how-do-i-fix-malformed-line-errors-in-sources-list)

To make a long story short, I attempted to enhance my 11.10 OS by installing the Satanic edition. Unfortunately, it's not compatible with 11.10 (a fact that I discovered too late)
and as a result of attempting to install the packages separetly, I ended up with E:Malformed line 55 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse) if there is a way to fix this, that would be great. But I've grown weary of Ubuntu 11.10 anyway & I wanted to give Kubuntu a try-or at least go back to 11.04. Well, I can't get either disc to run as a live cd with the option of granting me a full installation to replace 11.10. They have exe files that won't open on Linux. How can I fix this so I can return to 11.04 or try kubuntu?
thanks for any advise in advance.

Comment: You should clarify what you want to fix either want to install **Kubuntu** or want to fix **source.list** .

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove Ubuntu before you install *Kubuntu*; Its installer will offer you to use the old Ubuntu partition on the hard drive.

If you want to check which hard drive and partition this is, in Ubuntu, go to System → Administration → Disk Utility. Find your hard disk and parition and look for the "device" field. The openSUSE installer will let you install there, and wipe out all of the data that was there before. It will also install a new boot-loader and detect all of the operating systems on your computer.

or try

You can install on top of the Ubuntu installation without any preparation. Simply insert the disk, boot it, and when asked to partition, select "Replace existing Linux installations" or similar. It works like a charm